# Как найти координаты тех символов, которые не использовались?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть два txt-файла, один txt-файл содержит матрицу (паззл)

```
vlrtakeon
itredflow
ntuemturn
trgteaylp
arraysryi
gshjshhkg
etoesingg
```

а другой содержит слова, которые нужно найти с паззла

```
vintage
take
flow
remark
tea
array
toe
sing
turn
red
pig
```

Нужно найти координаты неиспользованных символов и вывести на экран. Слова могут искаться горизонтально, вертикально и по всем диагоналям. Каждая буква может использоваться по несколько раз.
Лучшее что смог составить это нахождение каждого слова, но, наверное, с этим еще далеко.

```
with open("puzzle.txt") as f:
    puzzle =[list(line.strip()) for line in f]
with open("words.txt") as f:
    words =[line.strip() for line in f]

print(words)
 
puzzle_h = [''.join(i) for i in puzzle]
puzzle_v = [''.join(i) for i in [*zip(*puzzle)]]
words = [''.join(i) for i in words]
 
print(*puzzle_h, sep='\n')
print('=' * 20)
 
for word in words:
    for j in puzzle_h:
        if j.find(word) != -1:
            print(f'{word}\t in {j}')
    for j in puzzle_v:
        if j.find(word) != -1:
            print(f'{word}\t in {j}')
```

Знаю что нужно работать в двумерных массивах, изначально так и поступил, но не могу понять, как связать каждую букву так, чтобы понять какая буква была не использована. Хотел написать функцию, которая для каждого символа из первого массива возращает True если буква была использована, и False если была не использована, но функция считает те буквы не по порядку, а просто проверяет, есть ли буква из второго массива в первом массиве (если объединить буквы то получится же слово).

Ну и вот, можете объяснить, как нужно написать функцию так, чтобы соблюдался строгий порядок символов

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы нашли слово

```
if j.find(word) != -1:
```

то индекс в строке, возвращаемый find, соответствует диапазону индексов в матрице. Эти ячейки можно пометить в дополнительной матрице.

В конце непомеченные ячейки соответствуют неиспользованным буквам

Comment: но по сути, я для поиска слов по вертикали использовал уже другой массив, поэтому там выведутся ненужные мне буквы

Comment: Диапазон индексов в транспонированном массиве соответствует некому диапазону в столбце исходного массива

Comment: хотите сказать, что если буду обращаться к координатам какого то символа в первой матрице, то автоматически буду обращаться к тем же координатам в транспонированной матрице?

Comment: Индексы поменяются местами A[i][k] соответствует B[k][i]